# Android studio strange behavior

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm facing a very strange behavior with android studio. I'm using `java 1.8 update 40`. Here is my class

```
public class ControlPanelController {
    Context context;
    ControlPanelView controlPanelView;

    public ControlPanelController(Context cont, ControlPanelView controlPanelView){
        this.context = cont;
        this.controlPanelView = controlPanelView;

        addClickEvents();
    }

    private void addClickEvents() {
        controlPanelView.configureSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

in `addClickEvents()`, `configureSpeaker` is my button in `controlPanelView`. I'm adding `click` event here on `Button`.
When i run my program, it is not displaying toast. because that button has not received `click` event. I'm not able to find out the reason behind it. Any help?

Comment: Add logcat and some more codes.

Comment: in addClickEvents, change the button's background or do something else to it that is easily visible. It's possible that, due to some coding error, the button you are setting on click and the button you are pressing are not actually the same.